# Replace characters in string with another character and switch back

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Quick note - I am very new to c# so I apologize if this is stupid simple.

I am having a hard time trying to complete a simple c# task in a book.

Pseudocode-

Text box text = user input

if button one is clicked
  replace all capital letters in the text box with an asterisk

else if button two is clicked 
  replace the asterisks with their original characters (back to normal)

Here is what I have so far

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
            button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string orignalText = textBox1.Text;


            if (sender == button1)

            {
                string replaced = Regex.Replace(orignalText, @"[A-Z]", "*");
                textBox1.Text = (replaced);

            }

            else if (sender == button2)

            {
                textBox1.Text = (orignalText);
            }


        }


    }
}
```

The problem is that button2 is showing the text with the asterisks. It should be showing (I want it to show) the original characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `originalText` should be a class field instead of a local variable. Also you should not store a textbox's value in case if someone clicked on the `button2`. Try to replace your `ClickedButton` method with this:

```
    string orignalText;

    public void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == button1)
        {
            orignalText = textBox1.Text;

            string replaced = Regex.Replace(orignalText, @"[A-Z]", "*");
            textBox1.Text = replaced;
        }
        else if (sender == button2)
        {
            textBox1.Text = orignalText;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues. First, you're setting the originalText before knowing which button was pressed. Second, originalText is a local variable, so when you want to replace it back in, it won't contain the original text anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to globalize `originaltext` variable and move the line

```
string orignalText = textBox1.Text;
```

into the first `if` check.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
        button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickedButton);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    string orignalText = null; //you should define this var outside of ClickedButton method to keep its value during button1/2 clicks

    public void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender == button1)
        {
            orignalText = textBox1.Text;
            string replaced = Regex.Replace(orignalText, @"[A-Z]", "*");
            textBox1.Text = replaced;
        }
        else if (sender == button2)
        {
            if (orignalText != null) textBox1.Text = orignalText;
        }

    }

  }
}
```